# Proving that every invertible linear transformation can be written as a composition of diagonalizable and a unipotent linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am reading Linear Algebra: An Introductory Approach by Curtis.

This is what I want to prove:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over an algebraically
> closed field $F$. Let $T$ be an invertible linear transformation on
> $V$. Then $T=DU$ where $D$ is a diagonalizable and $U$ is a unipotent
> linear transformation.

Note that a unipotent linear transformation $U$ is by definition such that $1-U$ is nilpotent.

I am familiar with the Primary Decomposition Theorem, Triangular Form Theorem and the Jordan Decomposition Theorem.

I have not been able to prove this but here my attempt:

Let $T$ be a linear transformation on $V$. Since the field $F$ over which $V$ lies is algebraically closed, we can write $T=D+N$ where $D=f(T)$ and $N=g(T)$ for some polynomials $f,g\in F[x]$ and are diagonalisable and nilpotent respectively by the Jordan Decomposition Theorem.

Can some clever algebra do the trick here on the linear transformations? Hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a detail about the additive Jordan normal form $T = D+N$ you haven't used: $D$ and $N$ commute with each other.  Therefore $D^{-1}N$ remains nilpotent, and hence $U = 1+D^{-1}N$ is unipotent.

Comment: How does it follow that $D$ is invertible? A hint would suffice.

Comment: @ashK in your question, the problem statement says that $T$ is an invertible linear transformation, so it cannot have $0$ as an eigenvalue. Hence, $D$, whose diagonal entries are the eigenvalues, is also invertible.